# как передать данные из одного окна в другое в PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt5

есть два окна:
Loading Window

```py
class Ui_StudentWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, StudentWindow):
        StudentWindow.setObjectName("StudentWindow")
        StudentWindow.resize(383, 530)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(StudentWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.img.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 211, 271))
        self.img.setObjectName("img")
        self.marks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.marks.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 290, 381, 192))
        self.marks.setObjectName("marks")
        self.marks.setColumnCount(0)
        self.marks.setRowCount(0)
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 0, 141, 31))
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 40, 141, 151))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.FIO = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.FIO.setObjectName("FIO")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.FIO)
        self.school = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.school.setObjectName("school")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.school)
        self.class_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.class_user.setObjectName("class_user")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.class_user)
        self.gender_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.gender_user.setObjectName("gender_user")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.gender_user)
        self.dob = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.dob.setObjectName("dob")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dob)
        StudentWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(StudentWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 383, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        StudentWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(StudentWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        StudentWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(StudentWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StudentWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, StudentWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StudentWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("StudentWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.img.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "Фото"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "Выйти"))
        self.FIO.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.school.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.class_user.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.gender_user.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.dob.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
```

и Student Window

```py
class Ui_LoadingWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        LoadingWindow.setObjectName("LoadingWindow")
        LoadingWindow.resize(218, 230)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(LoadingWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 160, 110))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.password.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.password, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.login = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.login.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.login.setObjectName("login")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.login, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.entry = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.entry.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 75, 23))
        self.entry.setObjectName("entry")
        LoadingWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 218, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        LoadingWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        LoadingWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(LoadingWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoadingWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        LoadingWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("LoadingWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Пароль"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Логин"))
        self.entry.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Войти"))
```

вот сам бэк-енд

```py
class LoadingWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_LoadingWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('LoadingWindow')
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("students.db")

        self.entry.clicked.connect(self.search)
    def search(self):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        user_id = cur.execute("""select id from users where login = ? and parol = ?""",
                                  (self.login.text(), self.password.text())).fetchall()

        if user_id:
           self.main
           self.wS = StudentWindow()
           self.wS.show()
           self.close()
        else:
           valid = QMessageBox.question(self, '',
                                         "Неверный логин или пароль", 
                                                           QMessageBox.Ok)


class StudentWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_StudentWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StudentWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('StudentWindow')
        self.main = parent
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.egress)

    def egress(self):
        self.wL = LoadingWindow()
        self.wL.show()
        self.close()
```

Надо чтобы из LoadingWindow переменная `user_id[0][0]` передавалась в StudentWindow и уже от туда выводилась в label

Comment: Вы пожалуйста когда обновляете вопрос, как-то давайте об этом знать. Посмотрите обновление в моем ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо так надо:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_StudentWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, StudentWindow):
        StudentWindow.setObjectName("StudentWindow")
        StudentWindow.resize(383, 530)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(StudentWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.img.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 211, 271))
        self.img.setObjectName("img")
        self.marks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.marks.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 290, 381, 192))
        self.marks.setObjectName("marks")
        self.marks.setColumnCount(0)
        self.marks.setRowCount(0)
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 0, 141, 31))
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 40, 141, 151))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.FIO = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.FIO.setObjectName("FIO")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.FIO)
        self.school = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.school.setObjectName("school")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.school)
        self.class_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.class_user.setObjectName("class_user")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.class_user)
        self.gender_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.gender_user.setObjectName("gender_user")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.gender_user)
        self.dob = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.dob.setObjectName("dob")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dob)
        StudentWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(StudentWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 383, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        StudentWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(StudentWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        StudentWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(StudentWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StudentWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, StudentWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StudentWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("StudentWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.img.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "Фото"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "Выйти"))
        self.FIO.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.school.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.class_user.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.gender_user.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.dob.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))


class Ui_LoadingWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        LoadingWindow.setObjectName("LoadingWindow")
        LoadingWindow.resize(218, 230)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(LoadingWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 160, 110))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.password.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.password, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.login = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.login.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.login.setObjectName("login")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.login, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.entry = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.entry.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 75, 23))
        self.entry.setObjectName("entry")
        LoadingWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 218, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        LoadingWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        LoadingWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(LoadingWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoadingWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        LoadingWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("LoadingWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Пароль"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Логин"))
        self.entry.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Войти"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_LoadingWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.entry.clicked.connect(self.onEntryClicked)

    def onEntryClicked(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.studentWindow = Ui_StudentWindow()                   
        self.studentWindow.setupUi(self.window)
        self.studentWindow.exit.clicked.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.studentWindow.FIO.setText(self.login.text())        # <---

        self.window.show()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sqlite3

class Ui_StudentWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, StudentWindow):
        StudentWindow.setObjectName("StudentWindow")
        StudentWindow.resize(383, 530)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(StudentWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.img = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.img.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 211, 271))
        self.img.setObjectName("img")
        self.marks = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.marks.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 290, 381, 192))
        self.marks.setObjectName("marks")
        self.marks.setColumnCount(0)
        self.marks.setRowCount(0)
        self.exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 0, 141, 31))
        self.exit.setObjectName("exit")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 40, 141, 151))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.FIO = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.FIO.setObjectName("FIO")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.FIO)
        self.school = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.school.setObjectName("school")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.school)
        self.class_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.class_user.setObjectName("class_user")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.class_user)
        self.gender_user = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.gender_user.setObjectName("gender_user")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.gender_user)
        self.dob = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.dob.setObjectName("dob")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dob)
        StudentWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(StudentWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 383, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        StudentWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(StudentWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        StudentWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(StudentWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StudentWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, StudentWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        StudentWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("StudentWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.img.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "Фото"))
        self.exit.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "Выйти"))
        self.FIO.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.school.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.class_user.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.gender_user.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.dob.setText(_translate("StudentWindow", "TextLabel"))


class Ui_LoadingWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        LoadingWindow.setObjectName("LoadingWindow")
        LoadingWindow.resize(218, 230)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(LoadingWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 160, 110))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.password.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.password.setObjectName("password")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.password, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.login = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.login.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.login.setObjectName("login")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.login, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.entry = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.entry.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 75, 23))
        self.entry.setObjectName("entry")
        LoadingWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 218, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        LoadingWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(LoadingWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        LoadingWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(LoadingWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoadingWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, LoadingWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        LoadingWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("LoadingWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Пароль"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Логин"))
        self.entry.setText(_translate("LoadingWindow", "Войти"))


class LoadingWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_LoadingWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LoadingWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('LoadingWindow')
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("students.db")

        self.entry.clicked.connect(self.search)

    def search(self):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
#        user_id = cur.execute("""select id from users where login = ? and parol = ?""",
#                                  (self.login.text(), self.password.text())).fetchall()

        if not self.login.text() or  not self.password.text():
            valid = QMessageBox.question(self, '',
                                        "Неверный логин или пароль", 
                                        QMessageBox.Ok)
            return

        user_id = (self.login.text(), self.password.text())

# ?        self.main
        self.wS = StudentWindow()

        self.wS.FIO.setText(user_id[0]) 

        self.wS.show()
        self.close()


class StudentWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_StudentWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StudentWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('StudentWindow')
# ?        self.main = parent
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.egress)

    def egress(self):
        self.wL = LoadingWindow()
        self.wL.show()
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = LoadingWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: привет, хочу адекватно разобраться в pyqt но методичек или годных уроков не нашел, можешь что подсказать??

Comment: @finally привет, все туториалы клоны http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/ . Почитай здесь http://it.kgsu.ru/Python_Qt/pyqt5_001.html . Важна практика.

Comment: да с удовольствием, есть уже хорошая идея, но чтобы реализовать надо неплохо расшарить